# Calculate math operation in textbox. [VBA] [EXCEL]

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, ms-word

i have numbers with plus, minus in textbox.

Can i calculate this math operation?

TextBox1.Value = 5+5+4-4

Can i calculate this?

Comment: why are you asking. just try it. you will never learn anything if you do not experiment.

Comment: i tested this and not working.

Comment: If you executed the statement in your question, it should have put the text `"10"` into your `TextBox`, so I assume what you mean by that part of your question is that your `TextBox` contains the string `"5+5+4-4"` and you want to evaluate it.  If so, try something like `Dim x As Double: x = Evaluate(TextBox1.Value): MsgBox x` and see what happens.

Comment: (Previous comment about `TextBox1.Value = 5+5+4-4` placing `10` into the `TextBox` applies to a `TextBox` with a name of `TextBox1` on a user form - it may not work for a `TextBox` placed onto an Excel worksheet itself.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Working, thanks!

Comment: @Dzejkob, your question should have contained this line instead ... `TextBox1.Value = "5+5+4-4"`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying to do with the [Evaluate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel) available with VBA.

```
TextBox1.Value = Application.Evaluate("5+5+4-4")
```

This will succesfully set the value to **10** as the result of your operation is 10.